# Custom CheckBox Padding issue

Tags: android

I am having a strange issue while designing custom checkbox. So as against default CheckBox i need a CheckBox with check on right side of the text, while there will be another drawable to left of the text as shown below :

[image]

As we can see, there some padding added to left of the CheckBox. Which i am not sure why..
I use below xml layout :

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/timer_options_skipped"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@null"
    android:checked="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/btn_check"
    android:text="CheckBox2"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/timer_options_conflicts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@null"
    android:checked="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock"
    android:drawablePadding="1dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/btn_check"
    android:text="CheckBox1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/status2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check ur size of ur image

Comment: If the problem is with the space marked with red(you don't want it), this is probably caused by the parent property " android:layout_width="match_parent" and the fact they all have the same weight. Change the width to wrap_content and see how it looks.

Comment: Image is an android resource so, i dont see any problem with it. @Laviniux : Its just the same with wrap_content

Comment: I think that is space taken by checkmark(android:button) if it was not set to "null". I used Motorola XOOM for testing and observed the above issue. But when i ran the code on Nexus 7 and this problem is NOT there. May be device specific issues..